# How to create new variable out of current variable contents

Tags: variables, batch-file, set

I have a variable "var1" with contents of "sharp=soothe"

```
var1=sharp=soothe
```

How do I create a new variable using only var1 contents to get this

```
sharp=soothe
```

I want to use the set command somehow like this

```
set %var1%=
```

but I can't get further than this. I hope I don't have to search for strings before and after the = sign. I thought there would be a faster way than that.

OK, I am so close. I found some other code I'm using and this nearly works for an infinite number of variables but the set command syntax is wrong again.

```
set var1=unfilter=rem
set var2=mdegrain=rem

set n=0
:parseArgs2
set /a n+=1
if defined var%n% (
    set %var%n%%
    shift /1
    goto :parseArgs2
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove one character from your attempt :-)

```
set %var1%
```

If you have an "array" of variables: var1, var2, ... var20, then you can use a FOR /L loop with delayed expansion:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
rem define your variables here ...
for /l %%N in (1 1 20) do set !var%%N!
```

Or if you have a series of randomly named variables, a simple FOR will do:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
rem define your variables here ...
for %%V in (varA varB varC varD) do set !%%V!
```

---

***update in response to add-on question***

I don't see why you are using SHIFT, unless there is other code you haven't shown. I removed the SHIFT.

```
set var1=unfilter=rem
set var2=mdegrain=rem

set n=0
:parseArgs2
set /a n+=1
if defined var%n% (
  call set %%var%n%%%
  goto :parseArgs2
)
```

or

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set var1=unfilter=rem
set var2=mdegrain=rem

set n=0
:parseArgs2
set /a n+=1
if defined var%n% (
  set !var%n%!
  goto :parseArgs2
)
```

Comment: this works fine with `INI` files (every line contains `property=value`): e.g. `for /f "delims=" %%a in (file.ini) do set "$%%a"`. `$` to regain the  variables from memory.

Comment: One more thing! I don't know how many variables I will always have, could be 20, could be 22. Is there a way to automatically stop after the last defined variable is processed? I don't want to always have to edit that number 20. The "if defined" command should be able to be used here?

Comment: @dbenbam - I had another brainstorm. See first post again. The set command syntax is wrong again and I can't figure it out.

Comment: Yes, shift was left over from that other code. I was not needed. This answer works.

Comment: Unfortunately, I find I can't get my app to input the variables with an equal sign like above. I can only get this - var1=unfilter-rem. So I need to change all the hyphens to equal signs first, then I can use the code above. What is the best way to do this? Remember the number of variables can change. @dbenham any tips?

Comment: @tyee - use standard search and replace with variable expansion: `set !var%n%:-==!`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
set var1=sharp=soothe
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ("%var1%") do set %%a
echo %sharp%
```

or just:

```
for %%a in ("%var1%") do set %%a
```

Comment: Works nice! Now one more thing. I have about 20 of these type of variables to do the same thing with. I'm sure I can use another for loop somehow, maybe within this for loop?

Comment: +1, nice! and more interesting it doesn't work with "%%a" in quotes: `for %%a in ("%var1%") do set "%%a"`, I don't know, why not.

Comment: @endoro - Enclosing quotes don't work because `%%a` already contains quotes. Simply use `set "%%~a"` instead.

Comment: Just an observation: if you want to get the value of `var1` variable (for example, to assign it to `X` variable), you may do this: `set X=%var1%` or you may do this: `for %%a in ("%var1%") do set X=%%~a`; both forms are equivalent, but the latter is only used when an additional expansion is required, not when the value of `var1` can be directly accessed...

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps is this what you want?

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set var1=unfilter=rem
set var2=mdegrain=rem
set var10=resize=rem

for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%a in ('set var') do set %%b
```

In this method does not matter the *number* of defined variables nor its *order*; all defined variables are always processed.

**EDIT**: Below is the output when an `ECHO` command is placed before the `set %%b`:

```
set unfilter=rem
set resize=rem
set mdegrain=rem
```

Comment: It's not working here. What is the output of the 'set var' command? @Aacini